# avoid to open the same file include flex

Tags: file, include, bison, flex-lexer

I am learning flex and bison and I want to implement the #include  statement
I manage to do that with some code I found in the flex-manual  but I want to check if the same file is already open and analyzed.

for example the correct way is:

- myclass file: #include myclass2.fff
- myclass2 file: #include myclass3.fff
- myclass3 file: has some statements etc

but I want to avoid this from happening:

- myclass file: #include myclass.fff

I tried saving the name of every file that i opened to compare them before i open a new one but somehow this isn't working... Thanks in advance

```
    strcpy(filename[c], yytext);
    c++;
   for(i=0;i <20;i++){
      if(strcmp(filename[i],yytext)!=0){
                   include_stack[include_stack_ptr++] =YY_CURRENT_BUFFER;
                   yyin = fopen( yytext, "r" );                                                                      yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ) );
                   BEGIN(INITIAL);
            }                 
      else if(strcmp(filename[i],yytext)==0){
                        yyterminate();                            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is just wrong. You don't mention how it fails, but the following are all possibilities. (I'm going to go with #2 as the immediate problem, but fixing that might lead to the other ones.)

1. The basic problem is the logic of the test, which might be translated as "starting with the beginning of the list of included file names, check to see if the file to be included is different from the stacked value; if so, push it onto the include stack." That will push the new file onto the include stack 20 times, unless it happens to already be present in the file list.
2. Also, the number `20` is just pulled out of thin air. Unless you have overpushed onto the `filename` list, `c` will be less than 20 at that point, so eventually `i` will reach the value `c`, at which point the filenames will compare equal so the current filename has already been placed into the vector at position `c`. That will cause all filenames to be rejected.
3. You don't seem to be checking to make sure that `c` doesn't increase beyond the size of the `filename` vector. So you could well overwrite random memory with the `memcpy`.

Once you fix all those problems, you might look into using `yycreate_buffer`, `yypush_buffer_state` and `yypop_buffer_state` instead of trying to maintain the buffer state yourself. Using the interfaces provided by `flex` is much less risky than trying to get the details right without them. (I know this code was partially copied from the flex manual, but you left out the important stack overflow test. Much easier to use the simpler code from the previous example in the flex manual.)